# Create random Numpy array following a given distribution and trend

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I want to create data that follows the same distribution and trend of the sample data taken using numpy.

For example say I have an array **x** whose trend is *increasing* and the distribution is suppose *log normal*. Can I create another random array which follows same distribution and trend using numpy ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, numpy doesn't have the capability to fit distributions to your data. You can either do it manually using the method you like (MLE or MM) or you can use scipy that can fit distributions over your data like shown below:

```py
import scipy.stats as st

# Inferred parameters of the distribution
s, loc, scale = st.lognorm.fit(x)

# Distribution object
dist = st.lognorm(s, loc, scale)

# generate 1000 random samples
samples = dist.rvs(size=1000)
```

Scipy used MLE by default.

You will have to explore your data and look into the distributions that fit the best. Numpy or scipy can't do that for you.

Documentation of `fit` method: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit.html